# No value set in python memcache

Tags: python

I am trying to print a value that I have set in memcache but I get None, what am I doing wrong?

```
import memcache
mc = memcache.Client(["127.0.0.1:11211"])
mc.set("foo","bar")
foo = mc.get("foo")


print foo
>>None
```

Comment: What do memcached logs say?

Comment: @martineau I would guess http://gijsbert.org/cmemcache/index.html or more likely http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-memcached/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not have installed memcached binary application.
For linux you can install & compile from source the latest version found in http://memcached.org/
For windows users you may follow the next tutorial: http://www.codeforest.net/how-to-install-memcached-on-windows-machine